# upgraded jquery/jquery-ui and now event.stopPropagation(); doesn't work

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I wasn't sure how to phrase my question in the title. I hope this is clear enough.

I upgraded jQuery from something very old to 3.3.1, and also jQuery-ui to 1.12.1. I've also got jquery-migrate-3.0.1.min.js. And suddenly code that used to work is giving me an error, which I'm having trouble finding a solution to.

Here is the code:

```
ABC.Foo = {
  init : function() {
    $('#my-link').toggle(ABC.Foo.on, ABC.Foo.off);
    $('body').click(ABC.Foo.bodyClicked);
  },
  on : function(event) {
    $('#my-panel').show();
    $('#my-id').addClass('selected');
    event.stopPropagation();
  },
  off : function(event) {
    $('#my-panel').hide();
    $('#my-id').removeClass('selected');
    event.stopPropagation();
  },
  bodyClicked : function(event) {
    if ($('#my-id').hasClass('selected')) {
      $("#my-link").trigger('click');
    }
  }
};
```

And here is the error

```
application.js:34357 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'stopPropagation' of undefined
at HTMLAnchorElement.off (application.js:34357)
at HTMLAnchorElement.opt.complete (application.js:7268)
at fire (application.js:3269)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (application.js:3399)
at tick (application.js:7111)
at Function.jQuery.fx.tick (application.js:7437)
at schedule (application.js:6814)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`toggle(function, function)` is deprecated and was removed in jQuery 1.9

https://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

Comment: A ha! Thanks so much!

Comment: Should be simple to roll those into one and just check the class then use `toggleClass()